# Kendo UI Scheduler: single select

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, preventdefault, kendo-scheduler

In Kendo UI Scheduler I need event selection. Problem is `selectable:true` also enables multiselecting over <kbd>Control</kbd> key. How to prevent this?

I've tried subscribing to the `keydown` event and calling `preventDefault()` or `return false;` but with no luck. Any advice?

Comment: Did you use `PreventDefault()` or `preventDefault()`? And do you see any error in the console?

Comment: `preventDefault()`. `PreventDefault()` causes error, because no such function.